# How can we transfer the session data to another sub-domain, while cookies is disabled.?

Tags: cross-domain, php

We would like to know the source code for transfer the session data to the sub-domain.

```
www.xyz.com // session data transfer to dev.xyz.com
dev.xyz.com //
```

We are not able to get the data, if there is a Cookies Disabled by User end.  please suggest me.

Thanks

PPS

Comment: How do you track user's session then? Via GET parameter?

Comment: you can get the session id some other way.. using a get parameter for example (even if it's not the most elegant solution)

Comment: should we use php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com this script . for sending session values to sub-domains.

Comment: we are using Wordpress system. above this code for .htaccess file. Please suggest me , I m beginner in PHP session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I can think of is like this:

make a hash with visitor IP and browser and send it along with encoded ([base64](http://www.php.net/base64_encode)?) `$_SESSION` data to second server like:

```
file_get_contents('http://dev.xyz.com/gateway.php?session=$IPBrowser&session=$session')
```

on the second server save that to a `temporary table?`/`file` and redirect user to second domain.
then you check his info based on IP and Browser and apply SESSION data.

this a VERY vulnerable solution, but it's a solution. I posted this thinking you are using for `dev` purposes.

And no, I will not make the source code.

Comment: should we create any special encryption for session variable, i just want to protect the session data at any case.

Comment: if you transfer them like I told you .. base64 is enough because you are not showing to the client any information